# Can you explain me the output

Tags: python

I was in `class` section of python programming and I am confused here.

I have learned that `super` is used to call the method of `parent` class but here `Employee` is not a parent of `Programmer` yet it's called (showing the result of `getLanguage` method).

What I am missing?

This is the code,

```
class Employee:
    company= "Google"
    language = "java"
    def showDetails(self):
        print("This is an employee");

    def getLanguage(self):
        print(f"1. The language is {self.language}");


class Programmer:
    language= "Python"
    company = "Youtubeeee"
    def getLanguage(self):
        super().getLanguage();
        print(f"2. The language is {self.language}")

    def showDetails(self):
        print("This is an programmer")



class Programmer2(Programmer , Employee):
    language= "C++"
    def getLanguage(self):
        super().getLanguage();
        print(f"3. The language is {self.language}")



p2 = Programmer2();
p2.getLanguage();
```

This is the output,

```
1. The language is C++
2. The language is C++
3. The language is C++
```

Comment: in each case the parent language is being overridden by the child language. If you remove the variable `language` from the child `Programmer2`, then it will use the language variable of the parent in its place (`Python`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've bumped into one of the reasons why `super` exists. From the docs, [super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) *delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type*. Python bases class inheritance on a dynamic [Method Resolution Order (MRO)](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). When you created a class with multiple inheritance, those two parent classes became siblings. The left most is first in MRO and the right one is next.

This isn't a property of the `Programmer` class, Its a property of the `Programmer2` class that decided to do multiple inheritance. If you use `Programmer` differently, as in,

```
p3 = Programmer()
p3.getLanguage()
```

You get the error `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'getLanguage'` because its MRO only goes to the base `object` which doesn't have the method.

You can view the MRO of the class with its `__mro__` attribute.

```
Programmer.__mro__:
    (<class '__main__.Programmer'>, <class 'object'>)

Programmer2.__mro__:
    (<class '__main__.Programmer2'>, <class '__main__.Programmer'>, 
    <class '__main__.Employee'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some more explanation about the mechanics how the code in the question works. In its general form, `super()` [can be called with two arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super) `super(C, obj)` where `C` is a class and `obj` is an object. The object `obj` determines which classes should be searched for a given attribute and the Method Resolution Order (MRO) in which these classes should be searched. The class argument is used to restrict this search to only these classes that appear in MRO after `C`.

By [PEP 3135](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/) when `super()` is used without arguments inside a class definition, the class argument is automatically taken to be the class being defined, and the object argument is the object upon which `super` acts.

In the code in the question, when you call `p2.getLanguage()` then inside the definition of `Programmer2`, the code `super().getLanguage()` is tacitly replaced by `super(Programmer2, p2).getLanguage()`. MRO of `p2` is `Programmer2` -> `Programmer` -> `Employee` -> `object`, and the search for `getLanguage` starts after `Programmer2` i.e. with `Programmer` class, and it succeeds in this class.

Then, in the process of executing `getLanguage` method of `Programmer`, we again encounter `super().getLanguage()`. This is now replaced by `super(Programmer, p2).getLanguage()` since we are still working with the same object, but the call to `super` is inside `Programmer` class. MRO of `p2` is still `Programmer2` -> `Programmer` -> `Employee` -> `object`, but now the search for `getLanguage` starts after `Programmer` i.e. with `Employee` class, and it succeeds in this class.

In this way, even though `Programmer` does not inherit from `Employee`, the code `super().getLanguage()` inside `Programmer` succeeds, since it is applied to an object that has `Employee` in its MRO.